# Can child ImageView exceed its parent ViewGroup bounds?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I'm trying to implement animated logo wich consist of two ImageView inside RelativeLayout. One is logo icon and other is "rays" behind it. "Rays" can be 3x larger then logo. I want to be able to set dimensions for it compound view (for example 200dp x 200dp), and let logo stretch this area, and rays to go beyond it. Is it possible?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No. Long Answer: Use [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can! Use a **negative value** of `android:layout_marginLeft`,  `android:layout_marginRight`, `android:layout_marginTop` or `android:layout_marginBottom`. Although it is a bit of a hack.